# "RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have NCCL built in" error when running PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, cuda, nvidia, distributed-computing

[image: Screenshot of "RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have NCCL built in" error]

When I am running PyTorch code from another server, this exception just happens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You must install NVIDIA's NCCL on your machine. This will require CUDA to be installed also. Follow the steps on NVIDIA's website:

[NCCL Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/nccl/install-guide/index.html)